# positive definite function

Tags: positive-definite, gradient-descent

Let $\phi = [x1^2, x1x2, x2^2]^\top$.

$W_1 ^\top \phi(x)$ and $W^{* \top} \phi(x)$ are positive definite functions and $A$ is a rank-1 positive semi definite matrix ($0<$one eigenvalue$<1$, the rest of eigenvalues are $0$).

If we update $W$ as follows:
$W_2^\top \phi(x) =W_1 ^\top (I-e_{lr}A) ^\top\phi(x) + e_{lr}W^{* \top}A ^\top \phi(x)$,
is $W_2^\top \phi(x)$ a positive definite function?

I think if $e_{lr}$ is sufficiently small, it is true.

Comment: If $e_{lr} < 1/\lambda_{\max}(A)$, then $I-e_{lr}A$ will be PSD. But I'm not sure what this means overall because the notation on the positive definite functions is a bit strange; maybe you can clarify there?

Comment: Sorry for some omission. A positive definite function $W_1^\top \phi(x)$  means that the value of $W_1^\top \phi(x)$ is positive for all $x \neq 0$ and 0 only for $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but how does the matrix operate on $\phi(x)$? Does $\phi(x)$ return a vector and this results in $\phi(x)^TW_1^T\phi(x)$?

Comment: Sorry again. $\phi(x)$ is column vector so that $W_1^\top\phi(x)$ is a scalar function.

Comment: Wait but $W_1$ is an $n \times n$ matrix? and $\phi(x)$ is a vector of length $n$? Doesn't this result in another vector of length $n$?

Comment: $W1$  is also column vector.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'm not sure, then. If $A$ is PSD, then $x^TAx$ is a PSD function, but I'm not sure about $x^TAy$ for $x\neq y$.